# I can't use second JFactory::getEditor in my Joomla Component

Tags: joomla, components, joomla1.7

**When I use second JEditor in JPane, second one is not shown properly. I just got a textarea.
Code works Joomla 1.5. I am adapting my code to Joomla 1.7.  **

```
echo "<div id='editor1'>";
$editor =JFactory::getEditor();
$params = array( 'smilies'=> '0' ,
         'style'  => '0' ,  
         'layer'  => '0' , 
         'table'  => '0' ,
         'clear_entities'=>'0'
         );
echo $editor->display( 'desc', '', '567', '400', '20', '20', false, $params );
echo "</div>";
echo $paneTab->endPanel();
echo $paneTab->startPanel("İngilizce Açıklama","engaciklama");
echo "<div id='editor2'>";
$editor2 =JFactory::getEditor();;
$params = array( 'smilies'=> '0' ,
         'style'  => '0' ,  
         'layer'  => '0' , 
         'table'  => '0' ,
         'clear_entities'=>'0'
         );
echo $editor2->display( 'edesc', '', '567', '400', '20', '20', false, $params );
echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no point in calling it twice as [this is a singleton](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=/development/tags/1.6.x/1.6.3/libraries/joomla/factory.php&view=markup) - it returns the same object...